# Are there any official roles and/or names for the days of a tenday?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, time

Most places and communities in Faerûn seem to be using the [Calendar of Harptos](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Calendar_of_Harptos). A calendar that divides the year into 12 months of 3 tendays each, and a total of 5 holidays mushed between some of these months.

The *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* has a neat sub-chapter on said calendar in Chapter 1 ("Welcome to the Realms"), detailing the above information: ["Time in the Realms"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/welcome-to-the-realms#TimeintheRealms)

But, there seems to be no further information regarding single days. Being Central-European (and living in a Christian country), I am used to the idea of our Monday to Friday being days when most people work; Fridays are days where piety is shown by consuming fish, Saturdays are somewhat divided, and Sundays are for church and family.

**What (if any) official WotC source(s) contain information on the meanings and uses of weekdays?**

Comment: there are so many deities on Faerûn ... most will probably have a "special" tenthday - could not find a link though so just speculation. If I needed some "special names" I would probably homebrew some days and "what to do" after the locally available / preferred deities.

Answer (score 18):

### No, there are no specific names

From the [Forgotten Realms Wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Calendar_of_Harptos):

> The days making up a tenday did not have formal names. If precision
>   was required, the number of the day and the number of the tenday were
>   used, as in, "the fourth day of the first tenday of Flamerule".

That passage itself references:

> [Ed Greenwood](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ed_Greenwood) (October 2012). *[Ed Greenwood Presents Elminster's Forgotten Realms](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ed_Greenwood_Presents_Elminster%27s_Forgotten_Realms)*. ([Wizards of the Coast](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Wizards_of_the_Coast)), *p. 19*. ISBN [0786960345](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Special:BookSources/0786960345).

Comment: ha! Just checked the reference in the link :) nice addition.

Answer (score -5):

Found this new reference: https://cityofsplendorsdungeonofmadness.obsidianportal.com/wikis/time-in-the-forgotten-realms

Quoted: In Waterdeep, the following days are associated with these deities:

First day (Lathander, day of the sun)

Second day (Selune, day of the moon)

Third day (Mystra, day of mysteries)

Fourth day (Tyr, day of justice)

Fifth day (Silvanus, day of the wild)

Sixth day (Oghma, day of the book)

Seventh day (Chauntea, day of grain)

Eighth day (Tempus, day of strife)

Ninth day (Kelemvor, day of the dead)

Tenth day (Sune, day of love)

Comment: I can’t find where that page sources this information. Are you sure that this is official? Given the other answer, this seems like it might just be made up.

Comment: @NautArch I agree. Seeing as Obsidian Portal is a Campaign Management Tool, there is no reason to treat anything found on there as authoritative (if they cite their sources, then those might be authoritative--but Obsidian Portal definitely isn't). We could be looking at official info, something from a third party source, or just something the DM of that campaign made up because they didn't like days of the week not having names.

Comment: sorry about that, I suppose it’s not “official”.